# Maltese Swadesh list with IPA

Tags: resource-request, swadesh-list

Do anyone know where to find the full Maltese Swadesh list with the phonetic transcription (IPA) ?. I found such list in Wikipedia but without IPA transcription

Comment: Fortunately, Maltese's writing system is almost phonemic. There are only a couple ambiguities, and not very important ones.

Comment: So you are not happy with the list on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Varieties_of_Arabic_Swadesh_lists) where most Maltese words have a link to their own wiktionary page with IPA?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any idea about how to pronounce the Maltese language that's why I seek for a fully transcribed list. However, I think the list on Wiktionary could significantly help me. Thank you a lot for your help